# How to set a fixed port for slc arc in docker container?

Tags: strongloop

I am using docker to build a strongloop application, and I want to try slc arc. But, I found the port was changed every times, such as 334564，39002...As you known, I had to map a port from docker container to local machine. How to fix this issue?  Was there a fixed port for slc arc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arc and most LoopBack apps will use the port given in the `PORT` environment variable if it is set.